# CSS Star Rating w/ radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I am working on a css star rating system with radios.
However I can't seem to work out what I am doing wrong here...it seems to highlight when I click...but it should be highlighting when I hover.

```
<fieldset>    
<input type="radio" id="star-5" name="rating-01" value="5"><label for="star-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star-4" name="rating-01" value="4"><label for="star-4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating-01" value="3"><label for="star-3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star-2" name="rating-01" value="2"><label for="star-2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star-1" name="rating-01" value="1"><label for="star-1"></label>
</fieldset>


input[type=radio] { display: none; visibility: collapse; }

input[type=radio] + label {
    position: relative; float: right; clear: none; display: block;
    width: 18.4%; height: 120px; margin: 0 1% 0 1%; padding: 0;
    outline: 0; cursor: pointer; 

    background-color: green;
}
input[type=radio]#star-1 + label { margin: 0 1% 0 0; } input[type=radio]#star-5 + label { margin: 0 0 0 1%; }

input[type=radio]:hover + label,
  input[type=radio]:hover + label ~ input[type=radio] + label {
      background-color: red;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

---

So this is what I managed to do so far: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypne7t2w/)**;

**CSS:**

```
input[type=radio] { display: none; visibility: collapse; }

input[type=radio] + label {
    position: relative; float: right; clear: none; display: block;
    width: 18.4%; height: 120px; margin: 0 1% 0 1%; padding: 0;
    outline: 0; cursor: pointer; background-color: green;
}
input[type=radio]#star-1 + label { margin: 0 1% 0 0; } input[type=radio]#star-5 + label { margin: 0 0 0 1%; }

fieldset > input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background-color: blue;
}

fieldset:hover > input[type=radio] + label:hover,
fieldset:hover > input[type=radio] + label:hover ~ label {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

However there still is a problem...when you select the boxes and they go blue. And you hover back the blue stays while the hovered over part is yellow.

How can I reset the blue once I hover over?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ntpom7a/ for me this is working...

Comment: @SimonHänisch Once you click and it highlights, and then remove the cursor and try and click again it won't work. Also it should highlight on `:hover` not on click..don't even know why it works on click as I haven't programmed `:checked`

Comment: for me nothing happens upon clicking...

Comment: @SimonHänisch Checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/ypne7t2w/ and the edited question.

Comment: @Boris please, check my solution posted below. I think that's what You are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Probably the simplest pure css solution you could come up with.

HTML

```
<div class="stars">
  <input type="radio" id="rate-5" name="rating-1">
  <label for="rate-5"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rate-4" name="rating-1">
  <label for="rate-4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rate-3" name="rating-1">
  <label for="rate-3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rate-2" name="rating-1">
  <label for="rate-2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rate-1" name="rating-1">
  <label for="rate-1"></label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.stars {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.stars input[type=radio]:checked ~ label:after {
  background: blue;
}
.stars input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.stars input[type=radio]:first-child + label {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.stars:hover input[type=radio]:checked ~ label:after,
.stars label:after {
  background: green;
}
.stars label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  height: 120px;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.stars label:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  background: green;
}
.stars label:hover:after,
.stars label:hover ~ label:after {
  background: gold !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rsyfchfo/

Hope this helps :)

**[update]** Added "reset selection on hover".

**[update2]** Added hover on white space between stars.

Comment: And interesting take for sure...but the grid doesn't reset on `:hover` if you choose to go back

Comment: Thats perfect! One more question...when you hover over the margin space, it seems to reset everything. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Boris I have updated the code to add hover on space between stars. https://jsfiddle.net/rsyfchfo/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! The padding fixed all or?

Comment: No problem :). I had to replace `margin` between stars with `padding`, and used `:after` pseudo-class to draw new blocks which don't fall into padding area between stars.

Comment: What about `!important` at the end...is there a way around without it?

Comment: That's the only weak part of this solution, I didn't found better selector to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

There is something I created long time ago. There is `javascript` too, for calculating total votes.

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tfm783cf/2/)

Code snipet :

```js
function showme(id) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'My vote : '+id.value;
    var r = document.getElementById('res').value.split(',');
    var s='';
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
      if(id.value==(i+1).toString()) {
        var x = parseInt(r[i])+1;
        r[i]=x.toString();
      }
      if(i==4) {s+=r[i];} else {s+=r[i]+',';}
    }
    document.getElementById('res').value=s;
    calc();
  }
  function calc() {
    var x=document.getElementById('res').value.split(',');
    var r=0;
    var t=0;
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
      t+=parseInt(x[i]);
      r+=(parseInt(x[i])*(i+1));
    }
    var s=parseInt((r/t)*20);
    document.getElementById('bar').style.width=s.toString()+'%';
    document.getElementById('sta').innerHTML=s.toString()+'%';
  }
```

```css
 #divRateCnt {
    width: 130px;
    position: relative;
}

#divRareCnt, #divStarsCnt{
    height: 26px;
    background: url(http://s4.postimg.org/wi683zp2h/stars.png) 0 0px repeat-x;
}

#divRateCnt input{
    display: none;
}

#divRateCnt label{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 26px;
    width: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#divRateCnt:hover label{
    display: block;
}
#divRateCnt label:hover{
    background: url(http://s4.postimg.org/wi683zp2h/stars.png) 0 -52px repeat-x;
}

#divRateCnt label + input + label{width: 104px;}
#divRateCnt label + input + label + input + label{width: 78px;}
#divRateCnt label + input + label + input + label + input + label{width: 52px;}
#divRateCnt label + input + label + input + label + input + label + input + label{width: 26px;}

#divRateCnt input:checked + label{
    display: block;
    background: url(http://s4.postimg.org/wi683zp2h/stars.png) 0 -52px repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="0,0,0,0,0" id="res" />
 <div id="divRateCnt">
  <div id="divStarsCnt"></div>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star5" value="5" onchange="showme(this);"><label for="star5"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star4" value="4" onchange="showme(this);"><label for="star4"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star3" value="3" onchange="showme(this);"><label for="star3"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star2" value="2" onchange="showme(this);"><label for="star2"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" id="star1" value="1" onchange="showme(this);"><label for="star1"></label>
 </div>
 <br>
 <span id="result"></span>
 <br><br>
 Total vote(s) :<br>
 <div style="width:130px;height:26px;background:url(http://s4.postimg.org/wi683zp2h/stars.png) 0 0 repeat-x;position:relative;">
  <div id="bar" style="width:130px;height:26px;background:url(http://s4.postimg.org/wi683zp2h/stars.png) 0 -26px repeat-x;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:0%;"></div>
 </div>
 <span id="sta"></span>
```

Comment: Can you please check out my updated question? Don't need JS calculations...it'll go to a DB.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/ypne7t2w/1/

this resets the label color when hovering the fieldset, but doesn't target the label hover:

```
fieldset:hover > input[type=radio] + label,
fieldset:hover > input[type=radio] + label ~ label {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Works great so far. But was thinking as i'll be using images to represent the stars. If the blue and gold are there I'll have to use the same image twice and that just increases the css. I tried combining the blue and yellow together, i get this now: https://jsfiddle.net/ypne7t2w/2/ the entire fieldset resets on hover. Any way to fix that?

Comment: using the same image url twice won't make the browser load it twice. once loaded the image is available everywhere on your site, as long as the url doesn't change (browser will cache it)... or do you mean that your css file size is increased because "url(file.jpg)" is a few characters longer than "green"? I don't think that these bytes will have any noticable impact on your page load time.